# Included php tag in html attribute

Tags: php

How do I include a php tag in an HTML attribute? I still find it quite tricky.

This is the HTML attribute:

```
src="https://customer.site.com/?language=en_US&portal=Default"
```

The thing is, ?language should accept a dynamic value. That value is stored in `$lingos[$wmpl_langcode]`.

So I've been trying many variations and I'm still stuck.

I've got this now but it doesn't seem right.

```
src=<?php echo "https://customer.site.com/?language=" . $lingos[$wmpl_langcode] . "&portal=Default" ?>"
```

I don't want to waste any more time on it. Any tips would be great.

Comment: *"but it doesn't seem right"* - Why doesn't it?  What is the output of that code?  How is it wrong?  How does it differ from manually writing the attribute?

Comment: I don't know, my Sublime is indicating that the code is not written correctly

Comment: Whatever "your Sublime" indicates have you tried **running** that code? Does it show any error message? And what **exactly** is indicated by your editor?

Comment: No I haven't tried running the code. I want to run code that first displays correctly in my code editor. I can't get my code editor to accept the code no matter how I write it. That's the reason I'm here to get some assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you was just missing one double quote and the `;` at the end of the `echo` to end the instruction:

```php
    src="https://customer.site.com/?language=<?php echo $lingos[$wmpl_langcode]; ?>&portal=Default"
```

Comment: The missing trailing semicolon should not be any problem

Answer (score 1):

You are now missing quotes for the attribute.

This however would be perfectly fine:

```
src="<?php echo "https://customer.site.com/?language=" . $lingos[$wmpl_langcode] . "&portal=Default" ?>"
```

If you like it a bit more clean without confusing quotes:

```
<img src="https://customer.site.com/?language=<?php echo $lingos[$wmpl_langcode] ?>&portal=Default"/>
```

You should also think about urlencode():

```
<img src="https://customer.site.com/?language=<?php echo urlencode($lingos[$wmpl_langcode]) ?>&portal=Default"/>
```

To make it "more clean", you should use a templating engine.

Answer (score 1):

When you directly use echo to print the dynamic link, the quotes are not present there.
Try this:

```
src="https://customer.site.com/?language=<?=$lingos[$wmpl_langcode] ?>&portal=Default"
```

OR

```
src="<?php echo "https://customer.site.com/?language=" . $lingos[$wmpl_langcode] . "&portal=Default" ?>"
```